# when install tablet wacom, with command depmod -a Message permission denied appears

Tags: wacom

I'm on ubuntu 12.04

I try to install the pilot of my tablet Wacom Intuos CTH480 with [this](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?) tutorial:

title Input-wacom

By the end, when I type this command:

```
depmod -a
```

this message appears:

```
FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/3.2.0-57-generic/modules.dep.temp for writing: Permission denied
```

What to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of typing `depmod` you should use sudo `sudo depmod -a`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But my tablet don't work anyway.